# How to upload hard coded image in php

Tags: php

I want to upload a particular image without using upload controls. My problem is that I am not able to pass the hard coded image path to `upload.php`.

upload.php:

```
<?php

  //i want to assign my image path here can any one tell me how to do that
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you post a file, it get's uploaded to a temp folder wich is somewhere in your server. It depends on your server configuration. If it is a shared server, the temp folder might be shared with other users as well. What you need to do is use the php function `move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $destination)` to copy it to the new path. If you don't do this, the temp file will get eventually deleted.

Comment: the tmp location can be defined in the php.ini file if you have access to it ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M